# Is there way to emulate Firebase Database locally?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I think question title is self explanatory, however following are more details

**Background**

I am developing one turn based android game with the help of Firebase realtime database. Concept is very simple, all players are connected to single room which I create by pushing into firebase database. Now every player attaches child value listener to that node. Now I can update game status in this node and everyone will get update in real time.

**Problem**

During development phase, I am still trying out different ways to structuring this data and implementing in android client. I am not working on any company or enterprise hence I have to use my own mobile internet (where internet data is costly). Plus many times I am in area where there is no internet connectivity. This reduces amount of time spent on testing any network related testing.

**Question**

Is there way I can simulate (or emulate) firebase database locally ? So that once it is working fine, I can test it on real network ? Any ideas or hints regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://youtu.be/7e0RGIul8Kk?t=30m36s)?

Comment: @AlexMamo, No I have not. I will check it out.

Comment: Does the cloud functions emulator emulate realtime database too?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you probably want to try [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server). It is basically a replacement Real-Time Database server that you can run locally.

You need to edit your OS's hosts file to make a 3-part domain name (like localhost.firebaseio.test) resolve to localhost, because of some weird restrictions built into the Firebase client libraries. Some people have found a way around this by injecting mocks into the client library, but this never worked for me; I think it only worked in an old version.

Note that this is NOT the officially recommended way to write unit tests; it's considered better to totally mock out the Firebase client library. It can be quite useful for integration tests, though.

There's a useful thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/Sl_aA0lSd78/Y7vNgFYACAAJ;context-place=topic/firebase-talk/CKM90JgJHI4) that covers some testing questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Firebase Local Emulator Suite** it has many modules (including the Realtime Database). Check their official docs here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=RTDB